# Add custom document properties to word with c#

Tags: c#, properties, ms-word

i try to add custom document properties to word with a c# tool.
I can edit the values of the builtin properties like author etc.

But with that code, i get no exception, but there is no custom property in the word document.

```
object oDocCustomProps;
string strIndex = String.Empty;
string strValue;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp =
    new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application { Visible = false };
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc =
    wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\\test.docx", ReadOnly: false, Visible: false);
oDocCustomProps = document.CustomDocumentProperties;
Type typeDocCustomProps = oDocCustomProps.GetType();
strIndex = "Testindex";
strValue = "Testvalue";
object[] oArgs = {strIndex, false, MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, strValue};
typeDocCustomProps.InvokeMember("Add", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
    null, oDocCustomProps, oArgs);
document.save();
document.close();
```

Edit

```
    public void addCustomDocumentPropertys()
    {

        object oMissing = Missing.Value;
        object oDocBuiltInProps;
        object oDocCustomProps;


        oDocBuiltInProps = oDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties;
        Type typeDocBuiltInProps = oDocBuiltInProps.GetType();

        //Get the Author property and display it.
        string strIndex = String.Empty;
        string strValue;

        oDocCustomProps = oDoc.CustomDocumentProperties;
        Type typeDocCustomProps = oDocCustomProps.GetType();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt_customAttributes.Rows)
        {
            strIndex = row[0].ToString();
            strValue = row[1].ToString();
            object[] oArgs = {strIndex,false,
                 MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString,
                 strValue};

            typeDocCustomProps.InvokeMember("Add", BindingFlags.Default |
                                       BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null,
                                       oDocCustomProps, oArgs);
        }
    }
```

Comment: My edit works for me... but  i dont now why :D

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same strange thing and it turns out that word does not save if you only change CustomDocumentProperties! You need to tell word that it must save by setting the doc.saved to false.

Hope this helps.
Best Regards
Frank

Comment: Much love Frank!

Comment: Where to set `doc.saved` ? How?

Answer (score 5):

By now you can do this:

```
  dynamic properties = null;
  try
  {
    properties = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties;

    // Testing purposes:
    properties.Add("SomeCustomProp", false, MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, "SomeCustomValue");
    properties.Add("SomeOtherCustomProp", false, MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, "SomeOtherValue");
    properties.Add("SomeNumericCustomProp", false, MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeNumber, 1982331);
  }
  finally
  {
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(properties);
  }
```

Releasing the COM object used to be recommended, but I'm not sure if it's still required.

Also, instead of

```
properties = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties;
```

just use your own reference to the application, then `.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties;`.

---

Note: this does the same as the edit in the question - just using dynamic instead of manual reflection.

Comment: All fine, but the changes won't be saved unless the document itself is saved. Any way to save the properties immediately as the added?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application { Visible = false };
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Doc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\\test.docx", ReadOnly: false, Visible: false);

Doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties["Title"].Value = this.Title.Text;
Doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties["Subject"].Value = this.Subject.Text;
Doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties["Category"].Value = this.Category.Text;
Doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties["Keywords"].Value = this.Keywords.Text;
Doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties["Author"].Value = this.Author.Text;
Doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties["Comments"].Value = this.Comments.Text;
```

Comment: I can edit the values of the builtin properties like author etc. but my problem is to add customDocumentProperties